# How to scale a fixed-width website to an iPad viewport

Tags: html, css, ipad, viewport

I need to be able to fit a 2560px wide website into an iPad's viewport. I currently have

```
@viewport { 
  width: device-width; 
  max-zoom: .15; 
  orientation: landscape;
}
@-ms-viewport { 
  width: device-width; 
  max-zoom: .15; 
  orientation: landscape;
}
@-o-viewport  {
  width: device-width; 
  max-zoom: .15; 
  orientation: landscape;
}
```

and it scales it to the viewport of the iPad, but I have to scroll horizontally to see the rest of the page.

All I need to do is scale the website inside of the viewport so it I don't have to scroll to see the rest of the page. I'm okay with there being space leftover in the viewport, but I can't have it overextending the viewport.

Does anyone know how I can scale a 2560px by 1440px website to fit in an iPad's viewport? The website's dimensions were set to fit a 2560px by 1440px monitor used as a tradeshow kiosk.

Thanks for the help in advance!

**EDIT:**

I've updated my CSS @viewport to:

```
@viewport { 
  width: 2560px;
  height: 1440px;
  zoom: .05; 
  orientation: landscape;
}
@-ms-viewport { 
  width: 2560px;
  height: 1440px;
  zoom: .05; 
  orientation: landscape;
}
@-o-viewport  {
  width: 2560px;
  height: 1440px;
  zoom: .05; 
  orientation: landscape;
}
@-webkit-viewport  {
  width: 2560px;
  height: 1440px;
  zoom: .05; 
  orientation: landscape;
}
@-moz-viewport  {
  width: 2560px;
  height: 1440px;
  zoom: .05; 
  orientation: landscape;
}
```

The only problem with my current configuration is I have about 50-100px of page runover in my viewport. So, I have to scroll to the right to view the rest of the webpage. I would like to be able to fit the entire webpage into the viewport, even if there's space between the viewport and my webpage.

I can't modify the width as it's all absolute positioning.

**UPDATE:**

I found a solution to my problem. Apparently the iPad was not taking my @viewport values, so I downloaded x-code and tested  tags. Other than a bit of spacing on the bottom of the webpage (to preserve an aspect ratio of 4:3 on the iPad), the webpage now fits nicely in the iPad's viewport.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=2560, height=1440, initial-scale=.40, user-scalable=no">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to set the meta viewport to the size you want eg below:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=2560,height=1440, initial-scale=1">
```

But Google has said that a fixed viewport is a bad method and you should use 'device-width' then make the website responsive.

[information about web master tools update](http://www.purerandom.co.uk/javascript/responsive-decided-)

Comment: Yeah, I tried this before and you're right, it should be responsive. Unfortunately, without changing a bit of the positioning of elements on the kiosk, I have to stick to the current dimensions.

Comment: Yeah, this just zooms into the webpage on the iPad.

Comment: Basically my current problem is with part of of the width hanging off the edge of the iPad viewport. So, the height is scaled properly, but I have to scroll to the right to see the rest of the content. I would like to be able to have the full interface in view without having to scroll. I am also okay with there being gaps, just as long as I can see and interact with the full webpage.

Comment: Your method was the most helpful in finding my solution. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try doing `width: 100%;` instead of `width: device-width;`

Example:

```
@viewport { 
  webkit-width: 100%; 
  webkit-max-zoom: .15; 
  webkit-orientation: landscape;
}
@-ms-viewport { 
  webkit-width: 100%; 
  webkit-max-zoom: .15; 
  webkit-orientation: landscape;
}
@-o-viewport  {
  webkit-width: 100%; 
  webkit-max-zoom: .15; 
  webkit-orientation: landscape;
}
```

Comment: This did not work, displays the same as "device-width;" on an iPad