# Do apple devices ignore CSS @viewport definitions?

Tags: css, mobile-safari, viewport

I am trying to find a way to set a different viewport initial scale for different devices. As far as i can tell, there is no way to do this using the meta viewport tag - i haven't found a way to use it in conjunction with a media query.

I was hoping that CSS @viewport could offer a solution, but i have been trying it to no avail. I used the following code inside the head of my HTML:

```
<style>
@viewport {zoom:.44;}                              
</style>
```

But found that it had no effect on either iphone or ipad. Both devices rendered the pages the same way they would if no viewport definition was in place. Do apple devices ignore the @viewport definition? I had similar results with width declarations. Is there any other way to make device-sensitive initial scale definitions?

Comment: [The MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@viewport) says that @viewport is not supported in Safari and Safari mobile. Does that answer your question?

Comment: It answers one of them. I'd love to know if there's any way to specify different viewport definitions for iphone and ipad, for example. I've tried to use a meta viewport tag with width=device-width but got very erratic results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get it to work in Safari, you'll need to specify in the meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

Comment: Hey Stephen P., I've tried using that but i get strange results - on the iphone the pages are zoomed in far too much and the edges cut off

Comment: @JonathanBasile Looks like the workaround is to define your Safari values in the meta tag, and then use the CSS for the other user agents (since Safari doesn't support the spec yet). Does this work for your use case? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26854011/how-to-scale-a-fixed-width-website-to-an-ipad-viewport

Comment: Well, that would work for everything except different apple devices - i was hoping to specify different definitions at least for iphone/ipad